# end up in error 613 as the SAP text is grayed out help me to bypass the error

Tags: excel, vba

Below my program, the error handler skips the error at first time but error occurs at the second time while in loop.

```
    Sub PGIChanges_Setup()
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
     
    lr = wb.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For x = 2 To lr
    
    A = Cells(x, 1)
    B = Cells(x, 2)
    
    
    
    If Not IsObject(App) Then
       Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
       Set App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
       Set Connection = App.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
       Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
       WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
    End If
    
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NVL02N"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLIKP-VBELN").Text = A
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\01").Select
    On Error GoTo step1
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:2102/ctxtLIKP-TDDAT").Text = "" 'Error occurs on this line 
    On Error GoTo step1
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:2102/ctxtLIKP-LDDAT").Text = ""
    On Error GoTo step1
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:2102/ctxtLIKP-WADAT").Text = B
    On Error GoTo step1
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:2102/ctxtLIKP-LFDAT").Text = ""
    On Error GoTo step1
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:2102/ctxtLIKP-WADAT").SetFocus
    On Error GoTo step1
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:2102/ctxtLIKP-WADAT").caretPosition = 10
    On Error GoTo step1
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
    
    On Error Resume Next
    step1:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
     Cells(x, 3) = "Done"
    Else
     Cells(x, 3) = "Error"
    End If
    
    Next x
    
      MsgBox "PGI has been updated !!! Please check it  "
    
      
    
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't copy-paste the same text several times. That's definitely not going to help you, most likely you just get less people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is.  The first thing I see is that you don't understand the "on error goto" statement.  You are using it multiple times when once is enough.  The first time you say "one error goto step1" you are enabling the error handler.  You are saying "if an error happens, jump to step1"  This will remain in effect until you have a different "on error" statement, such as "on error resume next", which says "if an error happens, just skip the line with the error and keep going"  To turn off the error handler,  you should issue "on error goto 0"

I think the issue is that the first time through the loop the code before your first "on error goto step1" line is unprotected, so if there is a runtime error, it will stop you code.  However, the second time through the loop, the code before your first "on error goto step1" statement is subject to either the "on error goto step1" from the first time through the loop if there was an error or is subject to the "on error resume next" if there was no error.

I think the code will behave as you expect if you add "on error goto 0" just after "For x = 2 To lr"

Good luck with your project.